# How to send object to class parameter javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem sending a parameter to the class. I want to do a class that supports error in AJAX. The working function looks like this:

```
function GetLastChangePass(UserId) {
    var field =
    {
        id: UserId,
    }
    var fieldStringified = JSON.stringify(field)
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Users/LastChangePass",
        method: 'PUT',
        data: fieldStringified,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: (result) => {
            if (result.includes('12.12.2000')) {
                document.querySelector('#user-tslog').append('')
            } else if (result == 'Not_tslog') {
                document.querySelector('#user-tslog').append('')
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector('#user-tslog').append(result)
            }
        },
        error: (result) => {
            addNewMessage("error", "Error")
            console.error("fail responseText: " + result.responseText)
            console.error("fail contentstatusText : " + result.statusText)
            console.error("fail status  TEST: " + result.status)
        }
    });
}
```

I made a class that looks like this:

```
class ErrorConsole {
    constructor(result) {
        this.result = result
}

    error() {
        console.error("fail responseText: " + this.result.responseText)
        console.error("fail contentstatusText : " + this.result.statusText)
        console.error("fail status : " + this.result.status)
    }
}
```

Why is the parameter undefined after converting the function to what is below?

```
        error: (result) => {
            console.log(result) //===> there is object

            addNewMessage("error", "Error");
            err.error(result) //===> there is indefined

            console.error("fail responseText: " + result.responseText)
            console.error("fail contentstatusText : " + result.statusText)
            console.error("fail status  TEST: " + result.status)
        }
```

Comment: What is `err` supposed to be? at line `err.error(result)`

Comment: I forget write.
    const err = new ErrorConsole()

Answer (score 0):

You should create the ErrorConsole and passing result in the constructor and not in the function, so that way you can print object attributes:

```
 error: (result) => {
        console.log(result) //===> there is object
        const err = new ErrorConsole(result) 

        addNewMessage("error", "Error");
        err.error()

        console.error("fail responseText: " + result.responseText)
        console.error("fail contentstatusText : " + result.statusText)
        console.error("fail status  TEST: " + result.status)
    }
```